# How to construct a smooth function with compact support satisfying $f(x)+f(x^{-1})=1$

Tags: analysis

How to construct a smooth function with compact support satisfying
$$
f(x)+f(x^{-1})=1
$$

For example, let
$$
g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0,&\mbox{if $x\leq 0$},\\
\frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{1-x}}},&\mbox{if $0<x<1$},\\
1,&\mbox{if $x\geq 1$},
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then
$$
G(x)=g\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)g\left(\frac{d-x}{d-c}\right)
$$
is a smooth function which equals 1 on [b,c] and vanishes outside (a,d).
However, I don't know how to modify it to satisfy $$
G(x)+G(x^{-1})=1
$$

Comment: What have you tried? Can you do this without the constraint that $f(x)+f(x^{-1})=1$?

Comment: Yes, i can do this without the constraint $f(x)+f(x^{-1})=1$.

Comment: For example, let $$
g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0,&\mbox{if $x\leq 0$},\\
\frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{1-x}}},&\mbox{if $0<x<1$},\\
1,&\mbox{if $x\geq 1$}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$ Then $$G(x)=g\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)g\left(\frac{d-x}{d-c}\right)$$ is a smooth function which equals 1 on $[b,c]$ and vanishes outside $(a,d)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $g : \Bbb{R} \to [0, 1]$ be a smooth function such that

- $g(x) = 1$ for $x < -1$,
- $g(x) = 0$ for $x > 1$,
- $g(x) + g(-x) = 1$.

For example, we may define

$$ g(x) = \int_{x}^{\infty} C \exp\{-(1-t^{2})^{-1}\} \mathbf{1}_{(-1,1)}(t) \, dt, $$

where $C = \left( \int_{-1}^{1} \exp\{-(1-t^{2})\} \, dt \right)^{-1}$ is the normalization constant.

Now define

$$ f(x) = g(\log|x|) $$

with the convention that $f(0) = 1$. Then $f$ is a smooth function supported on $[-e, e]$ and satisfies all the desired properties.